# QT how to wait for 1 threads to wait for the other 1 threads to execute

Tags: qt

How to wait for 1 Thread to wait for the other 1 Thread to execute in qt.

I try use `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` but two thread all wait
my program like this: one thread is A,other thread is B, in thread A   send signal to command thread B work,then in thread B send signal to command thread A work

**ExecuteTask class:**

```
class ExecuteTask : public QObject
{
  void doWork()
  {
   //do something
   emit toShow();
  }
}
namespace Ui {
class ShowData;
}

class ShowData : public QWidget
{
  connect(this , &ShowData::toDoThing, myTask, 
         &ExecuteTask::doWork, Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
  connect(myTask , &ExecuteTask::toShow, this, 
         &ShowData ::dealShowData, Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
}
void ShowData::dealShowData()
{
   emit toDoThing();
}
```

Comment: please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question now is not clear. what exactly are you trying to achieve and what do you get instead? please edit your question to clarify preferably with an MCVE.

Comment: What kind of questions is this one?
what's the point? you want to learn some thing new!
In Qt framework there are plenty of things to do with threads and one idea is QSemaphore.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly (which is very difficult), it would be much easier if you didn't use threads at all

Comment: If you do `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` then you have a dead-lock when the second emit happens, as each thread is waiting on the other.
If `this` needs to wait for `myTask::doWork` to finish, then use the blocking connection type here and not for the other one